# How interface gets a method with body from Object class?

Tags: java

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

interface My
{

    void show();

}

class Temp implements My
{

    public void show()
    {

        out.println("inside over-ridden show method");

    }

    public static void main(String... s)
    {
        My m = new Temp();
        m.show();
        String ob = m.toString();
        out.println(ob);
    }
}
```

output:

```
inside over-ridden show method

Temp@2a139a55
```

Interface 'My' gets toString() method from Object class and it is not implemented in the Temp class. Then how does an interface gets a method with body from Object class when all of its method should be abstract.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing the java Object class methods using an interface reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469333/accessing-the-java-object-class-methods-using-an-interface-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Interface 'My' gets toString() method from Object class and it is not implemented in the Temp class.

In addition to implementing `My`, class `Temp` extends `Object`. When you write

```
class Temp implements My {
    ...
}
```

it is the same as writing

```
class Temp extends Object implements My {
    ...
}
```

That is how it gets all methods from `Object`, including the default implementation of the [`Object.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

It is not "interface" getting method `toString`. All java classes inherit from Object inherently which as you noted has `toString` method. When you write

```
My m = new Temp();
```

your are creating a `Temp` object which has `toString` method because it subclasses Object inherently. `m` is just a variable of type `My`, which references `Temp` object after afore-mentioned line. it is really `Temp` object that has `toString` method inherited from Object class.